# Best practices for asking a question inside another thread

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, answers, best-practices

Is it considered bad form to post an answer inside another thread asking a related question to the OP's original question? Sometimes I would like to leave a question as a comment, but being a Stack Overflow newbie, I don't have the rep yet. Perhaps posting a question as a comment inside a preexisting thread is also bad form.

Comment: You will have enough rep to post comments asking for more information soon enough. Answers that are really comments or questions will likely be down-voted and will cost you rep and slow your progress toward being able post comments.

Comment: I was just a bit unsure of asking questions that might seem redundant. In these cases, sometimes it seems like my question is so close to the provided answer and I just need a bit more. I just didn't wanna add any cruft.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is "bad form". As your language acknowledges you're considering posting a question as an answer. This is a contradiction, and should therefore be avoided. Just a note, Stack Overflow and all Stack Exchange sites are not forums; they're question and answer sites and there are no "threads" - there's questions and answers.

If you need to ask another question then please ask one. Build on the question that you want to reference, acknowledge it, and explain what extra you want to do including your attempts and what you think you're doing right and wrong.

Commenting only requires 50 reputation, that's one good answer or 25 decent edits. It should only take you a few hours and in getting there you'll have given something worthwhile to the community. If you need to comment make that contribution and you'll be able to do so.

Comment: I just want to add to this that it is perfectly fine to link to the question which you are "building on" so people have a reference of the research you have done. You can explain that you read "this question" but you still have a question about "this part". Then ask a clear, precise question about why/where you are stuck.

Comment: I thought that's what I was implying with _"acknowledge it"_ @codeMagic, but thanks for making it explicit.

Comment: No problem. *I* knew what you meant but I just wanted to make sure that the OP did since SherMM is new. And because I've seen people ask if that is ok.